# Interfere one function from another function in java

Tags: function, jsf, interrupt, woodstock

I have two buttons in jsp namely Start and Stop.

**Expected:** Only Once Start button should be clicked, counting should start, and counting should be stopped when Stop Button is pressed.

(With reference to the code, When **Stop** button is pressed function **stop_action()** should be called, boolean **stopOperation** set to true and **while iteration should stop in start_action() **.)

**Actual:** Whenever the Start button is Clicked, new counting is started. Counting could not be stopped even pressing Stop Button many times.

**The code is as follows:**

In faces-config.xml, 
**FunctionExit (class, abcwar.FunctionExit) has request scope.**

and class FunctionExit is:

```
package abcwar;

import com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractPageBean;
import javax.faces.FacesException;

public class FunctionExit extends AbstractPageBean {

    private boolean stopOperation = false;

    private void _init() throws Exception {
    }

    public FunctionExit() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            _init();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("FunctionExit Initialization Failure", e);
            throw e instanceof FacesException ? (FacesException) e : new FacesException(e);
        }

    @Override
    public void preprocess() {
    }

    @Override
    public void prerender() {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    public String stop_action() {
        setStopOperation(true);
        System.out.println("getStopOperation() :" + getStopOperation());
        return "true";
    }

    public String start_action() {
        long steps = 0;
        while (!getStopOperation()) {
            steps++;
            System.out.println("Step Count :" + steps + ", getStopOperation() :" + getStopOperation());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean getStopOperation() {
        return stopOperation;
    }


    public void setStopOperation(boolean stopOperation) {
        this.stopOperation = stopOperation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After
**(i) defining the functions start_action(), stop_action()  and class variable boolean stopOperation in Session Scoped Class, SessionBean1

(ii) making Stop Button's Disabled Property = !Start Button's Disabled Property**


the expected behaviour has been achieved.

The code is as follows:

```
package abcwar;

import com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.AbstractSessionBean;
import javax.faces.FacesException;

public class SessionBean1 extends AbstractSessionBean {
    private boolean stopOperation = false;
    private long steps = 0;

    private void _init() throws Exception {
    }

    public SessionBean1() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {

        try {
            _init();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("SessionBean1 Initialization Failure", e);
            throw e instanceof FacesException ? (FacesException) e : new FacesException(e);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void passivate() {
    }


    @Override
    public void activate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    protected ApplicationBean1 getApplicationBean1() {
        return (ApplicationBean1) getBean("ApplicationBean1");
    }

    public boolean isStopOperation() {
        return stopOperation;
    }

    public void setStopOperation(boolean stopOperation) {
        this.stopOperation = stopOperation;
    }

    public String stop_action() {
        setStopOperation(true);
        System.out.println("getStopOperation() :" + isStopOperation());
        return null;
    }

    public String start_action() {
        if (steps <= 0) {
            steps = 0;
        }
        setStopOperation(false);
        while (!isStopOperation()) {
            steps++;
            System.out.println("Step Count :" + steps + ", getStopOperation() :" + isStopOperation());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```